# topology mirror mirrors some vertices in the wrong direction

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, mirror, retopology

Ive got a perfectly symmetrical human body that was made with the mirror modifier
it has no doubles

when i use x mirror everything mirrors perfectly
When i use topology mirror and move half of the object on the x axis, it mirrors everything but the fingers and the feet, those stay on their position.
it behaves as if the mesh is not symmetrical

at the beginning there was only 2 vertices on the tip of the ringfinger that were not getting mirrored correctly, those areas got bigger everytime i did changes to the object with topology mirror

the interesting thing is, if i select all the problematic vertices and delete them, the problematic vertices appear somewhere else near the deleted vertices with lesser amount
i then recreated the missing vertices separately and joined and merged it back to the human body
it worked perfectly but at some point the vertices started to mirror wrongly once again, specially after adding subdiv modifier, they started to appear at the tip of the fingers again

i then just recreated the whole object new, retopologized from the beginning, everything worked fine until i started creating the feet
the same problem seems to appear when i start adding more vertices at a specific location